# How to restore my loss from a saved meta graph?

Tags: tensorflow, scope, restore

I have built a simple tensorflow model that is working fine.
While training I save the meta_graph and also some parameters at different steps.

After that (in a new script) I want to restore the saved meta_graph and restore variables and operations.

Everything works fine, but only the

```
with tf.name_scope('MSE'):
    error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y, yhat, scope="error")
```

is not going to be restored. With the following line

```
mse_error = graph.get_tensor_by_name("MSE/error:0")
```

> "The name 'MSE/error:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The
>   operation, 'MSE/error', does not exist in the graph."

there appears this error message.

As I do exactly the same procedure for other variables and ops that are restored without any error, I don't know how to deal with that. Only difference is that there is only a scope attribute and not a name attribute in the tf.losses.mean_squared_error function.

So how do I restore the loss operation with the scope?

Here the code how I save and load the model.

Saving:

```
# define network ...
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=10)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    # do training ..., save model all 1000 optimization steps
    if (i + 1) % 1000 == 0:
        saver.save(sess, "L:/model/mlp_model", global_step=(i+1))
```

Restore:

```
# start a session
sess=tf.Session()
# load meta graph
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('L:\\model\\mlp_model-1000.meta')
# restore weights
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('L:\\model\\'))

# access network nodes
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
X = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Input/X:0")
Y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Input/Y:0")

# restore output-generating operation used for prediction
yhat_op = graph.get_tensor_by_name("OutputLayer/yhat:0")
mse_error = graph.get_tensor_by_name("MSE/error:0") # this one doesn't work
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added sketches of both scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your training step back, the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph) suggests you add it to a collection before saving it as a way to be able to point at it to after restoring your graph.

Saving:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=10)
# put op in collection
tf.add_to_collection('train_op', train_op)
...
```

Restore:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('L:\\model\\mlp_model-1000.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('L:\\model\\'))
# recover op through collection
train_op = tf.get_collection('train_op')[0]
```

**Why did your attempt at recovering the tensor by name fail?**

You can indeed get the tensor by its name -- the catch is that you need the correct name. And notice that your `error` argument to `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` is a *scope* name, not the name of the returned operation. This can be confusing, as other operations, such as `tf.nn.l2_loss`, accept a `name` argument.

In the end, the name of your `error` operation is `MSE/error/value:0`, which you can use to get it by name.

That is, until it breaks again in the future when you update tensorflow. `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` does not give you any guarantee on the name of its output, so it very well may change for some reason.

I think this is what motivates the use of collections: the lack of guarantee on the names of the operators you don't control yourself.

Alternatively, if for some reason you really want to use names, you could rename your operator like this:

```
with tf.name_scope('MSE'):
  error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y, yhat, scope='error')
  # let me stick my own name on it
  error = tf.identity(error, 'my_error')
```

Then you can rely on `graph.get_tensor_by_name('MSE/my_error:0')` safely.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to that. It is working now. But do you have a clue why I can't restore from scope?

Comment: As I understand, the term "scope" identifies a larger layer that can be made of one or more components with "names." Hence to identify a tensor by name you need 'scope/layer'

Comment: Beware, I found out that restoring inputs x,y_ as tf.get_collection instead of tf.get_tensor_by_name, sometimes makes the feed_dict unhashable. There is some accruing dictionary very difficult to understand on the background.

Answer (score 1):

tf.losses.mean_squared_error is an operation not a Tensor, you should load it with
[get_operation_by_name](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name):

```
mse_error = graph.get_operation_by_name("MSE/error")
```

that should work, note that there is no need for ":0"